# How to correctly store setings

Tags: command-line

I have made my .bashrc give me two types of prompts;

longp: `xanth@X-VboxTux:~➤➤➤`  and

shortp: `➤`

I have done this by writing a 0 or a 1 to a file and then to determine what prompt should be shown an if else tree is in the PS1 line.

so my question is... Is there a better way to store a state than writing a 0 or a 1 to a file?

code;

```
bashrcpl=$(<.bashrcpl)
if [ $bashrcpl = "0" ] || [ "$(whoami)" = root ]; then
    if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        if [ "$(whoami)" = root ]; then
            PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[0;31m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]@\[\033[0;36m\]\h\[\033[0;32m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]➤\[\033[1;31m\]➤\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
        else
            PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;31m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]@\[\033[0;36m\]\h\[\033[0;32m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]➤\[\033[1;31m\]➤\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
        fi

    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
fi

# Alias to turn short terminal prompt on or off
alias shortp='echo "1" > .bashrcpl & source ~/.bashrc &> /dev/null'
alias longp='echo "0" > .bashrcpl & source ~/.bashrc &> /dev/null'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the state of `PS1` there is no way around saving it in some file. But you do not need to source the whole `~/.bashrc` every time you want to change your prompt. You just need to change `PS1` for that. Instead of aliases just use two functions that set `PS1` accordingly and save the state (or rather the matching function call) in `~/.bashrcpl` :

```bsh
shortp () {
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
    echo shortp > ~/.bashrcpl
}

longp () {
    if [[ ${EUID} -eq 0 ]]; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[0;31m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]@\[\033[0;36m\]\h\[\033[0;32m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]➤\[\033[1;31m\]➤\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;31m\]\u\[\033[0;32m\]@\[\033[0;36m\]\h\[\033[0;32m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]➤\[\033[1;31m\]➤\[\033[0;32m\]➤\[\033[01;34m\] '
    fi
    echo longp > ~/.bashrcpl
}

source ~/.bashrcpl
```

The last line loads the last prompt used (The file is sourced and the appropriate function is called).

Saving the state is only needed in order to load a new shell with the last set prompt. If you do not need this feature just remove both lines with `echo` and replace `source ~/.bashrcpl` with either `shortp` or `longp`, whichever you prefer.

Note: I removed the check for `$color_prompt`. Unless `$color_prompt` is exported in `~/.bashrc` it will not be availble when running either function in the interactive shell. You can always add another function for a monochrome prompt, if you need it.